# how to inject keys in properties file as environment variables in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-properties

I am having an issue with injecting keys in a properties file in Spring 4.2.1 as environment variables.

I have myapp.properties like below

```
myapp.test.data=1
dataSource.jdbcUrl=jdbc://h2:12456
auth.security.role=admin
```

please let me know how I can inject the above variables using environment variables.

I tried UPPERCASE_UNDERSCORE format somehow not worked.

Spring: 4.2.5-RELEASE

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:module.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />

    </bean>
```

Comment: suggest to move away from xml based to annotation based code...